# OpenSSL how to get the speed od AES-128 from the results I got

Tags: openssl, aes

so first what do these values stand for are they cycles per 3 seconds?

and can I how can I get the speed from these results for AES-128 ?

```
$pi@raspberrypi:~/iot_c3 $ openssl speed aes-128-cbc
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 1913880 aes-128 cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 532956 aes-128 cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 139795 aes-128 cbc's in 2.98s
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 35692 aes-128 cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 4474 aes-128 cbc's in 2.99s
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
built on: Fri Jan 27 22:44:27 2017
options:bn(64,32) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,long) aes(partial) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
aes-128 cbc      10241.50k    11407.75k    12009.23k    12223.61k    12257.86k
```

Comment: Please provide the text as text not as an image.

Comment: is that better?

Answer (score 1):

"n aes-128 cbc's" means n blocks of the given size were encrypted. The speeds are listed right there at the bottom. You can verify that aes-128 cbc encrypted 4474 blocks of 8192 bytes in 2.99 seconds, giving 4474 * 8192 / 2.99 = 12257.86k bytes per second.